# How to fix backend csv download not being created properly when sent to front end

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to download a set of data from a database as a csv from the backend. When the download occurs on the browser the csv only has [Object Object] in it.

Currently I have this in the API controller:

```
        public HttpResponseMessage GetListCsv(string fileName)
        {
            var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            var csv = _myService.DownloadCsv(fileName);                           

            var stream = new MemoryStream(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(csv));
            result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/csv");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = $"{fileName}.csv" };
            return result;
        }
```

And this is on the front end:

```
        axios.get('api/List/Csv?fileName=' + id, { responseType: 'arrayBuffer',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'text/csv'
        } })
            .then(resp => {                
                const saveData = (function () {
                    const a = document.createElement("a");
                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                    a.style = "display: none";
                    return function (data, fileName) {
                        const blob = new Blob([data], { type: "text/csv" }),
                            url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                        a.href = url;
                        a.download = fileName;
                        a.click();
                        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                    };
                }());

                const fileName = id + ".csv";

                saveData(resp, fileName);

                this.fetchData();
            });
}
```

And whenever that is run, a download is done on the browser with a proper file name and a csv is downloaded. The only thing in the csv however is just [object object].

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you still need help with that, please provide the code for `DownloadCsv` function.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the sample code that you may use and change as per your need -

1. Write a seperate function to return csv file data

```
        public async Task<CsvFileData> GetCsvFileDataAsync(DataModel model)
        {
            var csvFileData = new CsvFileData();

            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
                using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter))
                {
                    csvWriter.WriteHeader<DataModel>();
                    csvWriter.NextRecord();
                    csvWriter.WriteRecord(model);
                }

                csvFileData.Content = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }

            csvFileData.Name = $"test.csv";

            return csvFileData;
        }
```

2. In controller

```
    var csvFileData = GetCsvFileDataAsync(model);
            if (csvFileData == null)
            {
               // log error and return proper status code
            }

            return File(csvFileData.Content, "text/csv", csvFileData.Name);
```